# Как обращаться к классу внутри класса

Tags: java

Есть класс внутри него есть еще класс который публик, сделал

```
Class cs = new Class()
cs.VnutriClass
```

не могу так обратится к внутреннему классу вай?

Comment: Можно вопрос чуть подробнее расписать (например, полный код добавить)? Я не достаточно хорошо знаком с `Java`.

Comment: Внизу ответили всё ясным образом можете прочитать если интересно

Comment: Да, уже разобрался.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предположим, что у Вас есть некоторый (определенный Вами, а не тот, который `java.lang.Class`) класс `Class` с *вложенным* в него классом `VnutriClass`, и Вы пытаетесь запустить вот такой код:

```
Class cs = new Class();
cs.VnutriClass;
```

Здесь Вы создаете объект `cs` *внешнего* класса `Class` и далее пытаетесь обратиться к **полю** `VnutriClass` объекта `cs` класса `Class` и справедливо получаете ошибку на этапе компиляции, так как в классе `Class` нет **поля** `VnutriClass`. Ваша запись никоим образом не относится к взаимодействию с *вложенным* классом. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к **полю** класса.

Чтобы обратиться к *вложенному* классу извне, необходимо этот *вложенный* класс сделать *статическим*:

```
public class Class {
   public static class VnutriClass {};
}
```

и обращаться к нему через *внешний* класс:

```
Class.VnutriClass vnutriClass = new Class.VnutriClass();
```

Если же Вы хотите добавить к *внешнему* классу поле *внутреннего* класса, то можно сделать так:

```
public class Class {
    private VnutriClass mVnutriClass;

    public Class() {
        mVnutriClass = new VnutriClass();
    }

    VnutriClass getVnutriClass() {
        return mVnutriClass;
    }

    public class VnutriClass {};
}
```

и работать с *внутренним* классом так:

```
Class cls = new Class();
Class.VnutriClass vnutriClass = cls.getVnutriClass();
```

**Немного теории:**

В Java, класс, определенный внутри другого класса называется *вложенным*.

Существует два типа вложенных классов: *статические* и *нестатические*.

Статический вложенный (*static nested*) класс – это  вложенный класс, определенный с модификатором `static`. Вложенный статический класс не может непосредственно ссылаться на нестатические члены своего внешнего класса.

Нестатический вложенный класс называется внутренним (*inner*) классом. Внутренний класс имеет доступ ко всем переменным и методам своего внешнего класса и может непосредственно ссылаться на них таким же образом, как это делают остальные нестатические члены внешнего класса.

**Пример со статическим вложенным классом:**

```
public class Outer {
    public static class Nested {};
}
```

---

```
Outer.Nested nested = new Outer.Nested();
```

**Пример с внутренним классом:**

```
public class Outer {
    private Inner mInner;

    public Outer() {
        mInner = new Inner();       
    }   

    Inner getInner() {
        return mInner;
    }

    public class Inner{};
}
```

---

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.getInner();
```

Comment: а как нужно к нему обращатся?

Comment: @elik, Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Это один из лучших полученных мною ответов!Благодарю

Comment: А где пример с Нестатическим вложенный классом ?))

Comment: Очень классный ответ!все ясно и доступно !Да вы примеры пример как я и хотел теперь все стало наместа !!!Благодарен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Иронию понял, но пример добавил :)